# Which are correct between notated, represented, and expressed?

Tags: notation

I hesitated to ask this question here because this is mathematics cite. However, I think this is related to mathematical expression.

My question is like the following:

$$
x(t) \mbox{ can be _________ } \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n \phi_n(t)\mbox{.}
$$

1. notated as / to
2. represented as / to
3. expressed as / to

Which one is correct? If all are incorrect, please let me know appropriate expressions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> represented as, expressed as

These seem fine. However, there will be instances where words like "noted, denoted" and other words are preferable, or just as good.

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much. I don't have any severe challenges when I read English. However, writing is different :(.

Comment: @Danny_Kim I understand. Keep practicing! :)